# Script to grep on range of start/end text

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I am trying to write a script to grep output from a range based on text, not line numbers.

For instance, in my text file, I want to grep the output starting with `$hostname` and capture everything in between `$endText` and then output the data in between those to a file named `$hostname.txt`.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. But it sounds like you would be interested in learning more about Perl's [range operators](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#Range-Operators).

Comment: If it has to be perl then remove the awk, sed and grep tags (the grep tag is for the command-line grep tool, not some perl function that has the same name). If it doesn't then remove "perl" from the Subject line. Either way read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then edit your question to comply.

Comment: Sorry mob, yes I am trying to learn more about that.  My question is what is/are the operators to help me do that?  Pretty new to Perl and looking for some insight.

Comment: I said remove perl from the SUbject line, not remove it from the tags - if youd be OK with a perl solution then add it back to the tags along with the other tools youd be OK getting a solution in.

Comment: Now you've removed the [tag:perl] tag completely! Is this about Perl, or not?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any details, here is the boiler plate.

```
$ sed -n '/start/,/end/p' file > outputfile
```

or

```
$ awk '/start/,/end/' file > outputfile
```

Comment: You should know better than to answer questions that are unclear.

Comment: Karakfa, this worked.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @SpencerSheehan you just accepted the first (and only answer) you got after it got multiple downvotes. You might WANT to consider the possibility that it might not be the right solution to your problem but instead is just something that happens to produce the output you expect from some specific sample input you ran it on and will not do what you want/expect in future given other input or slight changes in your requirements. In general you will get out of a question in relation to the effort you put into asking the question.